# Deleting Stateful Sets in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift, statefulset

How to delete the Stateful Sets in Kubernetes permanently? They get re-created even after I delete them by setting `--force` and `--grace-period=0` flags.

I know I can delete them all by removing the deployment itself. I'm interested in knowing if there is any way to preserve the deployments and delete only unwanted Stateful Sets.

Comment: Confused for statefulset in  the title  and the deployment in the description.

Comment: Title talks the actual issue only. Deleting deployment is one of the ways to delete all the pods and so the Stateful Sets. I tried the suggested way of scaling down the deployment and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling the deployment to 0 will remove the pods, but will keep the deployment:

`kubectl scale deploy/my-deployment --replicas=0`